import DB: ERROR 1435 (HY000) at line 166292: Trigger in wrong schema
I am working on Hostinger with Woocommerce, then I "Create a new staging environment" on hPanel. I got failed status after few minutes. After contacting to the Hostinger Customer Support. They show me "import DB: ERROR 1435 (HY000) at line 166292: Trigger in wrong schema" at the first contact. Then I asking for more detailed information, they told me to export and import again and on my side it works fine when I tried to import to the staging database but still the staging website does not run. Any idea on what is this issue about "Trigger in wrong schema"? As my production database have no issue at all.
[Create Staging from hPanel](https://i.sstatic.net/QsLD3Qjn.png)
[Answer from customer support 1](https://i.sstatic.net/pzBUiWwf.png)
[Answer from customer support 2](https://i.sstatic.net/o0vdBvA4.png)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I found the problem is due to one of my table Triggers which can be updated on database. I just have to change the Trigger table which was schema_user.table_name to table_name. As Hostinger when import they unable to detect this issue. Thus, we will need to remove the schema_user so it will be able to create without problem.
